# Pass a constrained type to a method

Tags: c#, generics, types, .net-4.0

There a few similar questions here on SO, but none seem to quite answer my question..

I want to create a method which takes an Enum Type, and generates a List of ListItems for the UI. Something with a signature like this could work:

```
public static List<ListItem> ListItemListFromEnum(Type t)
{
    ...        
}
```

But I would prefer not to accept any type (t must be an Enum type)
So I could do something like this:

```
public static List<ListItem> ListItemListFromEnum(Enum e)
{
    Type t = e.GetType();
}
```

and just pass an enum of the correct type to the method. That would work fine, but I'd really like to take a Type parameter (as in my first example) but force it to be an Enum type.

Is this possible? Is there a way to do it with generics?
Thanks

Comment: You may want to have a look at http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/. Even when Jon Skeet doesn't answer, Jon Skeet answers. How Zen of him.

Comment: @dlev, you assume he's not answering *right now.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of C# 7.3, [this is now possible](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/104):

```
public static List<ListItem> ListItemsListFromEnum<T>() where T:System.Enum
```

And `T` will be constrained to an enum. Note you must use the type `Enum`, the keyword `enum` will not compile.

In prior versions of C#, this is not possible.

If you cannot use that version of C#, you can just accept the `Type` as you are and check the [`IsEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenum.aspx) property. If it is, throw an Exception.

```
public static List<ListItem> ListItemListFromEnum(Type t)
{
    if (!t.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Type must be an enumeration", "t");
    }     
}
```

Likewise you could do the same with a generic:

```
public static List<ListItem> ListItemListFromEnum<T>()
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Type must be an enumeration", "t");
    }     
}
```

The only negative there is you will get a runtime exception rather than a compile-time one.

Comment: Ya that's what I wanted. Guess I'll have to check at run time

Answer (score 1):

You can accept the `Type` and then throw if that type is not an `enum` type.  That is probably the best way (until C# allows generic type placeholders to be constrained by `Enum`, if ever).

```
public static List<ListItem> ListItemListFromEnum(Type t)
{
        if (!t.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The type passed in must be an enum type.");                
        }

        // ...
}
```

This is what C# itself does with many of the `Enum` class's static methods (such as `Enum.GetEnumNames()`).

Comment: I figured that, but wanted compile time checking

Comment: @Erix: Yep, I've run into that too, there's many places I've wanted to say `where T : Enum` but you can't (currently) in C#.